# c# implement a factory in scoped services inside background tasks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I don't know if the title is a bit confusing or not but I'm resolving a scoped service using a factory that heavily depends on query/headers in the [request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1) .

sample code :

```
public IRegisterer ScopedFactoryFor(Type ServiceType, Func<HttpContext, object> Factory)
{
   _services.AddScoped(ServiceType, resolver =>
   {
        IHttpContextAccessor currentContext = (IHttpContextAccessor)resolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        return Factory(currentContext.HttpContext);
   });
   return this;
 }
```

the factory `Func<HttpContext, object> Factory`is created somewhere else in the application but as said it **heavily** depenends on the headers/query sent .

I want to know if there is a good way I can resolve the same service depending on a another factory if there is no scoped context.

Comment: OK - first question - why is there a heavy dependency on request headers / query? Is this something that can be changed? I ask because this instinctively feels like a code smell.

Comment: @mrdnk its multi tenant stuffs that does depends on both hostname and query/headers some business requirements

Comment: Write an interface that exposes the properties from the request. Add an instance of that interface as a scoped service. Then write a Middleware that accepts the interface and populates the properties on it using the request. Add the Middleware early in the pipeline. Then inject the service interface where you need it (now populated with request info)

Comment: @dryadepy Ok cool, bit more info. And also seems to be asp.net - so I’d go for working out what we’re doing at this point - the controller / action level - can be abstracted out of complex. Sound good? Is there a single API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

OK my answer is simply this, come at the architecture in a different way...

This is less of a DI question, and more of an implementation question (depending on the abstraction layer).

As @pinkfloydx33 has suggested there is middleware that you can write to abstract some of the implementation, but this seems like a later down the road type deal.

Assumptions

- You get the call in a controller/action

My (tres / very) basic implementation...

```cs
public class HeaderQueryResolutionFactory : ITenancyResolutionFactory {
   public TenantInfoStrategy Resolve(IHttpContext context) {
      return new TenantInfoStrategy(context.Headers["tenantName"], context.Headers, context.Query); // NB. this may not be the actual names, and is just a signifier
   }
}


public SomeController {
    public SomeController(... ITenancyResolutionFactory tenancyResolver) {
        _tenancyResolver = tenancyResolver;
    }

    ...
    [HttpPost, ... (secure etc.)...
    public ResponseModel CalledAction () {

       TenantInfoStrategy tenantInfo = _tenancyResolvery.resolve(context); // context = http context.

        var tenantAction = await _tenantFactory(tenantInfo.TenantName, tenantInfo.Headers, tenantInfo.Query);

        // do something with tenantAction, perhaps a switch to create the action and appropriate service 

       _service.Act(tenantAction);
    }

}
```

Basically, you do not want to create resolve something directly against an input, it's much better to take the names provide them to a factory, and then work out whether its valid and makes sense.

Your DI just needs, an Interface, that resolves to ITenancyResolutionFactory